# Exclude columns from clearing in realm database

Tags: java, android, realm

Can i exclude two columns from clearing in Realm Database?
when i use `realm.clear(City.class)`.
For example i don't want to clear data on **name** and **location** columns 
When using clear method
I want to save it from clearing

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that. First, `Realm.clear()` is renamed to `Realm.delete()`.

Basically the purpose of this API is to delete all the elements which are the type of given class. It is NOT set the default values to all the fields of those elements.

For your use case, you need to iterate and call set all values manually. Something like:

```
RealmResults<City> results = realm.where(City.class).findAll();

for (City city : results) {
    city.setName(null);
    city.setZipCode(0);
}
```